# Prevent Bazel dependency tracking through a select

Tags: bazel

I want `bazel query 'deps(//MyLib)'` to be empty when `my_setting` is not set given the following build file:

```
name = "my_setting",
values = { "a": "b" },
)

cc_library(
name = "MyLib",
deps = select({"my_setting": [ "some_target"]])
...);
```

Currently `bazel query 'deps(//MyLib)'` lists `some_target`.
What is the best approach to solve this?

Write a custom `cc_library` or write a custom `select`?

Comment: `query` ignores configuration information and returns all values from select()s. `cquery` will use configuration information to select the correct value from select()s, so try using `cquery`